# Creating a line graph using ggplot2 without a set "y"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I guess I am trying to create a geom_line version of a geom_bar.  The reason I want to do lines is because when I enter

```
geom_bar(aes(fill = Decile), position = position_dodge())
```

I am stuck with ten segments and my bar chart looks extremely cluttered.
  I have 11 separate x variables going across the bottom.  
The problem is I dont know how to use the count as a "y" variable and have tried things like `..count..` and other approached but am completely lost. Any ideas?

---

Thanks for the help!

My data looks like this:

Name Decile Division
Joe 1 San Diego
Jan 1 New York
Jay 2 San Diego
Lue 3 Dallas
Suz 2 Seattle
tye 3 Dallas

```
MCD <- read.csv("Decile15.csv", header = TRUE)

MCD$MonthNo <- factor(MCD$MonthNo, levels = c(1:11), labels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"))

Decile_names <- c('1' = "Decile #1",
                '2' = "Decile #2",
                '3' = "Decile #3",
                '4' = "Decile #4",
                '5' = "Decile #5"
                 )





MCDGraph <- ggplot(na.omit(MCD), aes(MonthNo))

MCDGraph + geom_bar(aes(fill = Division), color = "black", position = "fill") +     facet_wrap(~Decile, nrow = 1, labeller = labeller(Decile = as_labeller(Decile_names))) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +     scale_fill_manual(values = c("#DA4424", "#24A0DA", "#F0BC0B", "#43F749", "#4348F7", "#F74369", "#D7B9F5")) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "black", size = .5)) + labs(x = "2017", y = "% of Leads Per Month By Division") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(size = 25))
```

This is what my % of grouped facet_wrap bar chart looked like.

I split those into 5 so that I could see five plots instead of 10 on one pdf sheet.  Also this is only divided into the 7 total divisions.  I want to do one that is divided into 10.  Here is an example I used to make my grouped regular without faceting anything.

```
MC <- read.csv("2017_Full_year.csv", header = TRUE)

MC$MonthNo <- factor(MC$MonthNo, levels = c(1:11), labels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"))



MCH <- ggplot(na.omit(MC), aes(MonthNo))

MCH + geom_bar(aes(fill = Division), position = position_dodge() ) + labs(x = "2017", y = "# of Leads") + theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 3, linetype = "solid"), axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14),
  axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 14)) + scale_y_continuous(name = "# Of Leads", breaks = seq(0,1000, 50)) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
  fill = "white"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "black", size = .5), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "black", size = .5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#DA4424", "#24A0DA", "#F0BC0B", "#43F749", "#4348F7", "#F74369","#D7B9F5"))
```

EDIT: Or should I just create a new csv with the the final counts for each Decile during each month already in it. This would be a quick fix and I can pull the numbers very easily from SQL server.  I was just hoping to do this without having to create a new file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question does not contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). This makes it hard to understand and answer your question. Please share relevant code, a small excerpt of your data and the expected outcome. You can find detailed information on how to create a goo MCVE for R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162).

Comment: You can try getting a line version of the geom_bar, would you rather facet it though?  Instead of `ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class)) + geom_bar( aes(fill = manufacturer), position = dodge)` You could do `ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = manufacturer), position = 'dodge', show.legend = F) + facet_wrap(~class, scales = 'free_x')+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust= 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I did facet_wrap another one where I had each Decile showing counts with them being grouped by Division.  Also did a percent version of this also.  I wanted one with 10 lines(for each decile) showing count for each Month for the year so far.  Sorry if I'm not explaining this well enough.

Comment: Could you post a representation of your data?  I noticed the one you did up top doesn't include `MonthNo` which is used in your plot.  Would something like this make do for a representation of it? `MCD <-tibble(Name = rep(c("Joe", "Jay", "Susan", "Nancy", "Mark"), 2),
                    Decile = sample(c(1,2,3, 4),10, replace = T) ,
                    Division = rep(c('San Diego', 'New York', 'Dallas','Seattle','LA'), 2), MonthNo = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),2))`

Comment: Yeah that would be a good representation.  My file has over 4,000 rows but yes, there is a unique key, 1 decile(1-10), 1 division(7 for each city), and 1 monthnumber (1-11 for when the record occured this year). I want to graph a line for each decile with the points of the line representing the quantity.  The x variable would be the Month number so 1-11 going across the bottom. Like Decile 2 had 300 occurances during month 3, Decile 5 had 600 during month 3.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this would look with your real data, but something you could explore that looks nice in situations like these are ridgeplots using the `ggrigdes` package.  Example is below:

```
  library(ggridges)
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)


  set.seed(99)

  MCD <- tibble(
                Name = sample(c("Joe", "Jay", "Susan", "Nancy", "Mark"), 1000, T),
                Decile = sample(1:10,1000, T) ,
                Division = sample(c('San Diego', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Seattle', 'LA'), 1000, T),
                MonthNo = sample(1:11, 1000 , T))


  MCD$MonthNo <- factor(MCD$MonthNo, levels = c(1:11), labels = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November"))

  MCD %>% group_by(Decile, MonthNo) %>% summarize(Count = n()) %>% 
       ungroup() %>%  mutate(Decile = factor(Decile)) %>%  
       ggplot(aes(x = MonthNo, y = Decile, height = Count, group = Decile, fill = Decile)) + 
       geom_density_ridges(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = F, stat = "identity", scale = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the ["geom_line version of geom_bar"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1HBe.png)

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1, 3,3, 10,10,10,10))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_line(stat="count")
```

UPDATE:
Here is the version based on the dataset from TBT8's answer

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(99)
#create dummy dataset 
MCD <- tibble(
Name = sample(c("Joe", "Jay", "Susan", "Nancy", "Mark"), 1000, T),
Decile = sample(1:10,1000, T) ,
Division = sample(c('San Diego', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Seattle', 'LA'), 1000, T),
MonthNo = sample(1:11, 1000 , T))

MCD$MonthNo <- factor(MCD$MonthNo, levels = c(1:11), 
labels = c("January", "February", 
"March", "April", "May", 
"June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November"))

#create a numeric months vector
MonthNum <- 1:11
names(MonthNum) <- levels(MCD$MonthNo)

#create a factor to be used for facets
MCD$DecileF <- factor(
  MCD$Decile, 
  levels=as.character(sort(unique(MCD$Decile),
                           decreasing = TRUE)))

ggplot(MCD, aes(x = MonthNum[MonthNo], col=DecileF)) + 
  geom_path(stat = "count") +
  #geom_point(stat = "count") + 
  facet_grid(DecileF~.) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name ="Month", limits=names(MonthNum))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it tells me stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x.  Maybe my data frame is a lot more complex I will edit my post to describe what I am dealing with.

Comment: that's why I put "aes(x=x)" . Can you please provide your code? Otherwise it'd be difficult to understand what the problem is...

Comment: I posted it above.  Your example worked.  Let me show what I mean.

Comment: I cannot run your code, because I do not have the file "2017_Full_year.csv". Can you please upload it somewhere. Or type "dput(MC)" in R console and paste the output if the data.frame is not very big.

Comment: My file has over 4,000 rows, there is a unique key, 1 decile(1-10), 1 division(7 for each city), and 1 monthnumber (1-11 for when the record occured this year). I want to graph a line for each decile with the points of the line representing the quantity. The x variable would be the Month number so 1-11 going across the bottom. Like Decile 2 had 300 occurances during month 3, Decile 5 had 600 during month 3. Decile 2 had 100 during month 7 etc.. I just want a different line for each decile.The problem is, I dont have the counts. Although I could at this point just make a new file

Comment: and have the total counts for each region by decile, but I have been deadset on trying to create it from the original data.  Now I'm just curious if it can be done.

Comment: 4K rows is not much. If you cannot upload your original file, just create a file with some dummy data having the structure similar to your true data and upload this file.

Comment: @Petey: should I update my answer and show you what I mean using the data from TBT8's answer?